# Como evitar usar el mismo Array en 2 clases diferentes?

Tags: java, java-swing

Me surgió esta duda al crear multiples clases y tener que crear el mismo array varias veces en estas clases:

```
private final static String[] types = { String.class.getSimpleName(), Integer.class.getSimpleName(),
            Date.class.getSimpleName(), Boolean.class.getSimpleName() };
```

Este Array contiene los valores: **"String", "Int", "Date", "Boolean"**, el objetivo del array es contener los items de un **JComboBox** que sera usado en ejemplo estas 2 clases:

**Clase 1:**

```
public class Clase1 extends JPanel {

private final static String[] types = { String.class.getSimpleName(), Integer.class.getSimpleName(),
                Date.class.getSimpleName(), Boolean.class.getSimpleName() };

JComboBox box = new JComboBox(types);
//codigo
}
```

**Clase2:**

```
 public class Clase2 extends JPanel {

        private final static String[] types = { String.class.getSimpleName(), Integer.class.getSimpleName(),
                        Date.class.getSimpleName(), Boolean.class.getSimpleName() };

        JComboBox box = new JComboBox(types);
        //codigo
        }
```

Como puedo evitar de crear/repetir la creación de este objeto en multiples clases, hay alguna **Best Practices** para esto?

Comment: desde que lo declaraste como static estaba resuelto sólo era que lo sacaras fuera como menciona Gastón

Comment: Funciona si, pero es menos correcto? en el sentido que lo ideal no seria crear una clase aparte para salvar el array?

Comment: Lo tienes estático, aunque lo tenias en la misma clase, lo estático siempre se carga antes que todo y se mantiene, así que ya era una cochinada antes y no se va a limpiar con lo que te propone Gaston

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declara el array estatico en una clase y luego lo llamas de las clases que necesites sin cambiarlo.

```
public class ArrayGlobal{

  public static String[] types = { String.class.getSimpleName(), Integer.class.getSimpleName(),
            Date.class.getSimpleName(), Boolean.class.getSimpleName() };
}
```

Luego en tus clases lo accedes con

```
import static ArrayGlobal.*;

 public class Clase2 extends JPanel {

      //Obtener el primer elemento
       types[0]; 

        JComboBox box = new JComboBox(types);
        //codigo
        }
```

Otra forma

```
public class Clase2 extends JPanel {

          //Obtener el primer elemento
           ArrayGlobal.types[0]; 

            JComboBox box = new JComboBox(ArrayGlobal.types);
            //codigo
            }
```